# How to Make an Installer for a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am really a New to this field and i have made a Chrome Extension but i need my website visitors to install the chrome extension from my website via an `.exe` file for my knowledge i know that has to be done with the help of an installer but i don't know how to do can some body help me please.

Comment: Chrome extensions are almost always installed as an extension, through Chrome itself.  Why do you need it as an exe?  This is foreign to how Chrome works *and* would restrict your extension to just Microsoft Window's users.

Comment: I've only saw this scenario once. The page MonsterDivx (dot com, i guess) provides you with an exe to install their plugin. This is, of course, because they will put Adds in your computer WITHOUT your permission, and far from Chrome Webstore rules. So, I recommend to not do it or google about the monsterdivx scenario, if that helps you.

Comment: Well Thank you for your answer, But For our users we need to install this plug in we have thousands of users i cant manually install this plug in for my users so that is the reason i am looking for a solution so that we will share that link to our users over email.